# How to drag drop multiple line on epache echarts?

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I try to make multiple line drag/drop on apache echarts using graphic util as below code (original code form apache echarts website).

```
setTimeout(function () {
    myChart.setOption({
        graphic: echarts.util.map(data_line1, function (item, dataIndex) {
            return {
                type: 'circle',
                position: myChart.convertToPixel('grid', item),
                shape: {
                    cx: 0,
                    cy: 0,
                    r: symbolSize / 2
                },
                invisible: true,
                draggable: true,
                ondrag: echarts.util.curry(onPointDragging, dataIndex),
                z: 100
            };
        }),
        graphic: echarts.util.map(data_line2, function (item, dataIndex) {
            return {
                type: 'circle',
                position: myChart.convertToPixel('grid', item),
                shape: {
                    cx: 0,
                    cy: 0,
                    r: symbolSize / 2
                },
                invisible: true,
                draggable: true,
                ondrag: echarts.util.curry(onPointDraggingLine2, dataIndex),
                z: 100
            };
        })
    });
}, 0);
```

This is update position function

```
function updatePosition() {
    myChart.setOption({
        graphic: echarts.util.map(data_line1, function (item, dataIndex) {
            return {
                position: myChart.convertToPixel('grid', item)
            };
        }),
         graphic: echarts.util.map(data_line2, function (item, dataIndex) {
            return {
                position: myChart.convertToPixel('grid', item)
            };
        })
    });
     
}
```

This is on drag function

```
function onPointDragging(dataIndex, dx, dy) {
    data_line1[dataIndex] = myChart.convertFromPixel('grid', this.position);

    // Update data
    myChart.setOption({
        series: [{
            id: 'a',
            data: data_line1
        }]
    });
}
function onPointDraggingLine2(dataIndex, dx, dy) {
    data_line2[dataIndex] = myChart.convertFromPixel('grid', this.position);

    // Update data
    myChart.setOption({
        series: [{
            id: 'b',
            data: data_line2
        }]
    });
}
```

But I can handle only the first line. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `graphic` twice in the options, and one is overwriting the other.

You should set it only once with an array that combines points from `data_line1` and `data_line2`, for example:

```
data_line1.concat(data_line2)
```

Then, depending on `dataIndex` call `ondrag` with `onPointDragging`, or `onPointDraggingLine2` and `dataIndex` or `dataIndex - data_line1.length`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).